# Android rateBar is getting cut off in my xml

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

I have an android rateBar that gets injected into my XML when a user adds a beer to their portfolio. When the ratebar shows up. I am trying to scale it so I can make it fit, on half the screen. When I insert it, looks like it should have room but gets cut off before reaching the edge of the screen:

[image]

The xml for my activity is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_card">



                <!-- Card Contents go here -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/beerTitle"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle = "bold"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    >
                </TextView>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="10dip"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/beerBreweryTitle2"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:textSize="10sp"
                            android:text="From: "
                            android:textStyle = "bold"
                            android:padding="5dip"

                            ></TextView>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/beerBreweryName"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:textColor="@color/orange"
                            android:textStyle = "bold"
                            android:padding="5dip"
                            android:onClick="viewBrewery"
                            android:clickable="true"

                            ></TextView>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/beerStyleTitle2"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:textSize="10sp"
                            android:text="Style: "
                            android:textStyle = "bold"
                            android:padding="5dip"

                            ></TextView>


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/beerStyleName"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:textColor="@color/orange"
                            android:textStyle = "bold"
                            android:padding="5dip"
                            android:onClick="viewStyle"
                            android:clickable="true"

                            ></TextView>


                        <TableLayout

                            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:shrinkColumns="*"
                            android:stretchColumns="*">

                            <TableRow
                                android:id="@+id/tableStatTitles"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                                android:padding="5dip" >

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/abvTitle"
                                    android:text="ABV"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textStyle = "bold"
                                    android:textSize="10sp"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"

                                    ></TextView>

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/IBUTitle"
                                    android:text="IBU"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textStyle = "bold"
                                    android:textSize="10sp"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"

                                    ></TextView>

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/glassTitle"
                                    android:text="Glass"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textStyle = "bold"
                                    android:textSize="10sp"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    ></TextView>




                            </TableRow>

                            <TableRow
                                android:id="@+id/tableStat"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                                android:padding="5dip" >

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/abv"
                                    android:text=""
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textSize="15sp"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    ></TextView>

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/IBU"
                                    android:text=""
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textSize="15sp"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    ></TextView>

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/glass"
                                    android:text=""
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textSize="15sp"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    ></TextView>


                            </TableRow>

                        </TableLayout>




                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>



            </LinearLayout >

        </FrameLayout>




        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_card">



                <!-- Card Contents go here -->


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="2">



                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Average Rating: "
                        android:textStyle = "bold"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/beerRating"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/yourPortfolio"
                            android:textStyle = "bold"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:text="Your Portfolio:"
                            android:padding="5dip"
                            ></TextView>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/addBeerLayout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical" >

                        </LinearLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>




            </LinearLayout >

        </FrameLayout>




        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_card">



                <!-- Card Contents go here -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/beerDescriptionTitle"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:text="Description:"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </TextView>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/beerDescription"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:padding="5dip"

                    ></TextView>




            </LinearLayout >

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_card">



                <!-- Card Contents go here -->
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonTasteTag"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:text="Taste Profile"
                    android:onClick="viewTasteTags"

                    />




            </LinearLayout >

        </FrameLayout>







</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And the rateBar that gets added into the xml has an xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:onClick="rateDialog">

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/beerRatingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1.0"
        android:rating="0"
        android:onClick="addRateToDB"
        android:scaleX="0.5"
        android:scaleY="0.5"
         />




</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try android:paddingRight??

Comment: wouldnt I not want padding? Or am I thinking of this all wrong?

Comment: Have you set the width to `fill_parent` and see if it fixes it?

Comment: Fill parent for a ratebar adds a ton of stars past what you set it too and it still gets cut off.